# Measuring time till end of last request

Tags: performance, web

Can people please point me to a tool that can track "time till the end of last request" for end users. NOT the OnLoad time; but the time till the end of last request; the kind that Firebug reports towards the bottom right of the net panel.The reason is that my site gets lots of data over AJAX, and user cannot really do much till the whole Ajax data is loaded.

Now I understand that may be I should redesign things; but back to this question - is there a tool that can track this for end users?

Google Analytics reports OnLoad Time

New Relic reports OnLoad time

Firebug does report time till last request, but is NOT real user monitoring; that is me manually firing some test requests. I do not need this.

Comment: try network panel (developer tools) of chrome and sort it using total time,end time

Comment: Nachiket, I can very well do that. But that is not end user time. That is the time it took me to do some operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no equivalent of NewRelic/Google Analytics that would let you do this out of the box.

Google Analytics has a nice feature, user timing, though which can be used to do exactly what I desire. Using 'user timing' I can pretty much define any event on the page, such as JS finished loading or some AJAX data coming back, as myOwnPageLoad event and then track it. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTiming